# Setting the key (legend) coordinates doesn't work?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to move the key to some location in the middle of the plot, so I followed the tutorials and have the following script:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color
set title "Risk of the loan"

set output 'simulation.eps'
set xlabel 'Initial loan value'
#set key height 24
set key 8,0.7

plot 'simulation.txt' using 1:2 title 'Discounted loan value' with lines lw 3,\
     'simulation.txt' using 1:3 title 'VaR' with lines lw 3,\
     'simulation.txt' using 1:4 title 'CVaR' with lines lw 3,\
     'simulation.txt' using 1:5 title 'Probability of default' with lines lw 3
```

However, when I run it I get:

```
ga1009@ga1009-dell:~$ gnuplot simulation.p

set key 8,0.7
        ^
"simulation.p", line 7: unknown key option
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
set key at 8,0.7
        ^^
```

Works here!

Comment: I had the same problem after reading a lot of online examples that omit the "at".  Thanks!